# CSS Documentation Template

Tags: css, documentation, templates

Does anyone know if there are CSS templates purely for documentation purposes? I haven't been able to find any.

**Edit:** Looks like I will have to write my own. Basically it would have been nice to have a little css template that has pre-styled notice boxes and lists purely for the use of user guides or documentation but not too hard to setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [960 grid](http://960.gs/)

it's basically a CSS framework

Answer (score 2):

[Blueprint CSS](http://www.blueprintcss.org/)
On a par with 960 Grid

Comment: i agree. Blueprint is very good too

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the designs at the [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.mezzoblue.com/zengarden/alldesigns/).

The goal of this site is to showcase what is possible with CSS-based design. Style sheets contributed by various graphic designers are used to change the visual presentation of a single HTML file, producing hundreds of different designs. The HTML markup itself never changes between the different designs.

On each design page, you'd have a link to view the CSS file of that design.